# TypeError: data.map is not a function - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is the *data*:

```
WebSQLRows {
  "_array": Array [
    Object {
      "id": 172,
      "user_na": "Yfug",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 173,
      "user_na": "Ihvb",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 174,
      "user_na": "Hfugu",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 175,
      "user_na": "Ffh",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 176,
      "user_na": "Hfhg",
    },
    Object {
      "id": 177,
      "user_na": "Gcug",
    },
  ],
  "length": 6,
}
```

This is the code I've used to get it:

```
data.map((item) => {
    console.log(item.id);
    console.log(item.user_na);
});
```

Error:
`TypeError: data.map is not a function.`

I want an output that only consists of the id, and `user_na`. 
I'm learning to use SQLite with React Native, and SQLite SELECT query gives me this.

SQLite Select:

```
const getData = () => {
    global.data = data;

    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM users", [], (tx, results) => {
        var len = results.rows.length;

        if (len == 0) {
          numFunc("The database is empty");
        } else {
          numFunc(len.toString());
          dataEntry(results.rows);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(data);
  };
```

Comment: data["_array"].map

Comment: @Viet `×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: show log `data` before use it

Comment: That gives me the above data format

Answer (score 0):

You are using `sqlite` query and you need to get array result. Based on  [Expo document](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/#resultset-objects) the `result.rows` has an `_array` which returns all the items as array.

So you can try this one:

```
if (result && result.rows && result.rows._array) {
   result.rows._array.map((item) => {
      console.log(item.id);
      console.log(item.user_na);
  });
}
```

Comment: @SaaiNatha I saw your edit suggestion why do you need `for loop` if you have `length` property in your `data` that means `data` is array and you can use `map` function. so you don't need to extra `for` loop

Comment: Ohk, but that gives me `TypeError`

Comment: Can you create a snippet. I am pretty sure your problem is not using extra `for` loop. See my answer it works correctly

Comment: @SaaiNatha what is the result of `console.log(data);` could you please show me the result?

Comment: Ok as you see  is object not array so you can't use `for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {..`

Comment: @SaaiNatha Still you get TypeError when you use `data["_array"].map((item)`??

Comment: Yeah, right. I get TypeError when I use `data["_array"].map((item)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235750/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-saai-natha).